# Cannot connect to Azure SQL from different region

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have got a trouble in connecting to my Azure SQL Server from a different country from my home. I am visiting abroad temporary and have found that server connection fails when try to connect to my SQL server with VS2015 server connection function.

It shows me the error 0: connection timed out or error 40: could not open a connection.

I can connect to the server when I use remote desktop connection to the computer in my home and try to do from it.

I have checked that my temporal ip is listed in the white list in the setting. Do I have to see another setting or do something else?

Comment: that is not that total error message,can you paste entire info

Comment: Is this with SQL Database service, or with a VM? It would help if you clarify (via editing your question), but I'm assuming SQL Service, since you mentioned a 'white list' (so, the SQL Service allowed-IP list for the server?). Have you confirmed that port 1433 is open where you're at?

Comment: I agree with @DavidMakogon's suggestion - have you added your IP address to the 'allowed' list?